# How do I solve IMPORT ERROR problem on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

When I run the following code on the Spyder console:

```
 !pip install pyqt5 lxml --upgrade
 !cd labelImg && pyrcc5 -o libs/resources.py resources.qrc
```

I get the following:

```
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.7-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\bakang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11 in c:\users\bakang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.0 in c:\users\bakang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (5.15.2)
Installing collected packages: pyqt5
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Bakang\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\QtCore.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bakang\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Bakang\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Bakang\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyrcc_main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .pyrcc import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyrcc: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

What could be the problem, Please help.

Comment: I am definitely not sure, but Spyder is an IDE, you typically don't invoke pip from the IDE.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: I used pip on the console though

Comment: Then why did you cite Spyder as a tag?

Comment: Clearly, this is your problem "Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: "  You need to figure out why you can't access the packages?  Possibly an Admin privilege